# Merging event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these event listeners:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow",function(e,ui){
    // do something
});
$(document).on("click","[data-json]",function(){
    // do something else
});
```

I can merge them like so:

```
$(document).on({
    pagebeforeshow: function(e, ui) {
        // do something here
    },
    click: function(e) {
        // do something else here
    }
});
```

... but I'm not sure how to bind the click to `[data-json]` as in the first example.

Comment: Don’t merge them? Reimplementing jQuery’s event delegation kind of defeats the point of doing so (assuming the point is clean/concise code).

Comment: Oh? why not? just so I know.

Comment: You can't merge regular event binding and delegation in the same call to `on`.

Comment: Why are you trying to merge two types of event handlers that can't be easily expressed in the same type of event handler?  The basic answer is to stop trying to merge them because a merged solution will be more complicated than two separate event handlers.  Keep it simple.

Comment: I thought if all the event handlers are in the same listener, it might be faster and also easier to read, no?

Comment: Not when the event handlers are not naturally compatible and additional code is required to reimplement delegated event handling.  Plus, your two event handlers and are not actually for the same object anyway.  One is for the `document`object, the other is for `[data-json]` elements.  I see no code clarity reasons for combining these and complexity reasons for not combining them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this line

```
click: function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is($("[data-json]"))) return;
}
```

it will simulate what you first example was doing. It only runs the function if element that is firing has attribute `data-json`

Comment: Except there's no reason to actually try to reimplement delegated event handling.  The OP should just stick with two event handlers so one can use the delegated event handling already built into jQuery.

Comment: i dont know op's full condition so i can't tell op to not do it